# Web Form to Oracle DB Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

How does one take user inputted values in an ASP.NET WebForm (Textboxes/Checkboxes/DDLs/etc.) and insert them into a database (Oracle, in my case, but not picky to which is explained).

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> INSERT into db field "Name"
<asp:CheckBox id "checkbox1" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox> INSERT into db field "Gender"
<asp:DropDownList id "dropdownlist1" runat="server"></DropDownList> INSERT into db field "ComputerType"
```

*Above are just sample controls to get an understanding of this topic.*

Comment: @George Stocker - I attempted to improve this question to make it more of a *real question*, and also more likely helpful to any other users that stumble upon this QA looking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straight forward:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO table ('Name', 'Gender', 'ComputerType') VALUES (@Name, @Gender, @ComputerType)";
using (OracleConnection c = new OracleConnection("{cstring}"))
{
    c.Open();
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, c))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textbox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", /* not sure how [checkbox1] maps here */);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComputerType", dropdownlist1.SelectedValue);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

the `sql` statement is parameterized, you open a connection and a new command with that connection, set the parameters based off the values in your controls, and execute the query.

Comment: @NickVielbig, not a problem, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Comment: Now that I think about it. As it's an oracle DB, aren't the parameters supposed to be prefixed with **:** rather than **@**? (Also, I am not finding AddWithValue as an available from Parameters, but Add does it properly on its own).